# Как посчитать сколько букв поместится в TextView Android?

Tags: android, android-textview

Мне нужно сделать приложение наподобие книги. Заполнить листы ViewPagera текстом. Проблема такая:

я хочу загрузить в первый TextView текст, но его либо слишком много либо слишком мало. Мне нужно узнать сколько текста поместится в на первую страницу, и на вторую страницу загрузить остальное.

Как посчитать сколько букв могут поместится в TextView если оно на полном экране?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно посчитать не кол-во букв, а кол-во строк которые можно разместить в textView. Например такой [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377873/how-to-know-that-how-many-characters-could-be-placed-in-one-line) при использовании [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextWidths%28java.lang.String,%20float%5B%5D%29):

```
int countLineBreaks(final TextView view, final String toMeasure) {

    final Paint paint = textView.getPaint();
    int startPos = 0;
    int breakCount = 0;
    final int endPos = toMeasure.length();

    while (startPos < endPos) {
        startPos += paint.breakText(toMeasure.substring(startPos, endPos),
                                   true,  tv.getWidth(),(float[]) null);
        lineCount++;
    }

    return lineCount;
}
```

вот например есть [функция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970785/9363441) для проверки насколько текст больше чем виджет:

```
private boolean isTooLarge (TextView text, String newText) {
    float textWidth = text.getPaint().measureText(newText);
    return (textWidth >= text.getMeasuredWidth ());
}
```

Так же вот варианты решения вашей проблемы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037377/how-to-get-number-of-lines-of-textview), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415169/android-how-do-i-know-how-many-text-can-fit-in-my-textview-my-page).

### UPDATE

Можно сетить текст в виджет. Дальше через:

```
textView.getText()
```

получаем текст который уже показан. Дальше получаем его размер:

```
textView.getText().length()
```

следующим этапом отсекаем от общего стринга тот который уже показан:

```
String nextChunk = originalText.subString(textView.getText().length(),originalText.length())
```

и соответственно его и показываем в следующей странице. Но чтобы эта система работала и на следующих страницах а не только на первой, то нужно суммировать показанный текст, и его отрезать от оригинала

```
int shownText += textView.getText().length()
```

и тогда нарезка текста будет выглядеть так:

```
String nextChunk = originalText.subString(shownText ,originalText.length())
```

осталось только придумать как адекватно переносить текст на следующую страницу, и не рвать слова.

Comment: эта функция почему то не работает, я уже все остальные варианты испробовал

Comment: я рекурсивно вызывал эту функцию и на каждом шаге уменьшал текст в двое, но тогда отображается только первая строка. Я пытался text.setText(newText.substring(0, textWidth.toInt())) , но тоже не работает

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: не получается, когда я беру размер или текст, то он возвращает мне его полностью

Comment: cпасибо Андрей ты подтолкнул на правильную мысль!!!!!

Comment: надеюсь что смог хоть чем-то помочь)) но если у виджета стоит wrap_content то полюбому нужно считать кол-во строк, в противном случае он будет выводить текст полностью. Принять ответ можно нажав на галочку слева от него :)

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал Андрей: можно узнать сколько строк занимает у меня экран, из этих строк вытащить текст и уаля ->

```
val maxLines = textview.getHeight() / textview.getLineHeight()
  val start = textview.layout.getLineStart(0)
  val end = textview.layout.getLineEnd(maxLines-1)
  val content = textview.text.toString().substring(start, end)
content.length
```